# Query embeddedlist combined with other property in OrientDB

Tags: java, sql, orientdb

I'm trying to query an embedded list in OrientDB in my Java application, but I have a hard time querying the property when I combine it with an other property.

For example, this works (the categories is an embeddedlist of Strings):

```
select from Book where categories = :category
```

However, when I query like this:

```
select from Book where categories = :category and year = 1980
```

Then suddenly my query gives no results anymore, while there are certainly books from the year 1980 in my DB with that category. Actually, all books in my site or from 1980 (but later, I'll also add books of 1981, and 1982, etc).

Both of the fields are indexed (NONUNIQUE index). Just as a test, I removed the index on the year, and behold, the query behaves normally again. Now I'm confused :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried your case with this simple structure:

```
CREATE CLASS Books

CREATE PROPERTY Books.title STRING
CREATE PROPERTY Books.categories EMBEDDEDLIST STRING
CREATE PROPERTY Books.year INTEGER

CREATE INDEX Books.categories ON Books(categories) NOTUNIQUE
CREATE INDEX Books.year ON Books(year) NOTUNIQUE

INSERT INTO Books(title, categories, year) VALUES('BookA', ['Fantasy','Adventure'], 1980)
INSERT INTO Books(title, categories, year) VALUES('BookA', ['Fantasy'], 1985)
INSERT INTO Books(title, categories, year) VALUES('BookA', ['Horror','Adventure'], 1984)
INSERT INTO Books(title, categories, year) VALUES('BookA', ['Adventure'], 1980)
INSERT INTO Books(title, categories, year) VALUES('BookA', ['Historical'], 1981)
INSERT INTO Books(title, categories, year) VALUES('BookA', ['Thriller'], 1990)
```

and this is the results in the class `Books`:

```
SELECT FROM Books

----+-----+------+-----+----------+----
#   |@RID |@CLASS|title|categories|year
----+-----+------+-----+----------+----
0   |#12:0|Books |BookA|[2]       |1980
1   |#12:1|Books |BookA|[1]       |1985
2   |#12:2|Books |BookA|[2]       |1984
3   |#12:3|Books |BookA|[1]       |1980
4   |#12:4|Books |BookA|[1]       |1981
5   |#12:5|Books |BookA|[1]       |1990
----+-----+------+-----+----------+----
```

The problem could be in the usage of the `=` instead of the `IN` operator, because `categories` is an `EMBEDDEDLIST` and the `IN` operator checks the existence of the input parameter in every value of the list (while `=` checks if the parameter value is exactly the same of the list value).

**OSQL**:

1) Using `=`:

```
SELECT FROM Books WHERE categories = 'Adventure' AND year = 1980

0 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.0 sec(s).
```

2) Using `IN`:

```
SELECT FROM Books WHERE 'Adventure' IN categories AND year = 1980

----+-----+------+-----+----------+----
#   |@RID |@CLASS|title|categories|year
----+-----+------+-----+----------+----
0   |#12:0|Books |BookA|[2]       |1980
1   |#12:3|Books |BookA|[1]       |1980
----+-----+------+-----+----------+----
```

3) Using `CONTAINS`:

```
SELECT FROM Books WHERE categories CONTAINS 'Adventure' AND year = 1980

----+-----+------+-----+----------+----
#   |@RID |@CLASS|title|categories|year
----+-----+------+-----+----------+----
0   |#12:0|Books |BookA|[2]       |1980
1   |#12:3|Books |BookA|[1]       |1980
----+-----+------+-----+----------+----
```

**JAVA**:

```
private static String remote = "remote:localhost/";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dbName = "DBname";
    String path = remote + dbName;
    OServerAdmin serverAdmin;
    try {
        serverAdmin = new OServerAdmin(path).connect("root", "root");
        if (serverAdmin.existsDatabase()) {
            System.out.println("Database '" + dbName + "' already exists");
            ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx(path);
            db.open("root", "root");
            Iterable<ODocument> results = db.command(new OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument>(
                    "SELECT FROM Books WHERE 'Adventure' IN categories AND year = 1980")).execute();
            for (ODocument result : results) {
                System.out.println("Title: " + result.field("title") + "   Category: " + result.field("categories")
                        + "   Year: " + result.field("year"));
            }
            db.close();
        } else {
            serverAdmin.createDatabase(dbName, "document", "plocal");
            System.out.println("Database " + dbName + " created");
        }
        serverAdmin.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Database 'DBname' already exists

Title: BookA   Category: [Fantasy, Adventure]   Year: 1980
Title: BookA   Category: [Adventure]   Year: 1980
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate answer! I'll test if it works. Much appreciated. But what is the difference between =, in, and contains??

Comment: Hi @Erik the differences are:

= is used to check if a condition match another one and it apply to any type of data

IN is used to check if a result is contained in any of the elements in a list and it used only with the collection

CONTAINS is used if the collection contains at least on element that satisfy the next condition and it used for the collection

For more information take a look here: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/SQL-Where.html

Comment: Hi Erik, I updated the answer with a `CONTAINS` example. Do you have a chance to try the queries ?

Comment: Hi @Erik, did you have a chance to try the queries ?

Comment: Hi @Erik, no problem. Glad to have been helpful.